# Where in the Ruby language is %q, %w, etc., defined?

Tags: ruby

So much of the Ruby language is methods rather than syntax, so I expected to find `%q`, `%w`, etc., defined as methods in the `Kernel` class.  However, they're not there.

So where are they defined?  Are they language keywords?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They are “hard coded” in the parser; see

- [parse.y from the tip of Ruby 1.9.2](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/branches/ruby_1_9_2/parse.y?view=markup) or
- [parse.y from the tip of Ruby 1.8.7](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/branches/ruby_1_8_7/parse.y?view=markup).

The easiest way to find the code in question is to look for the second occurrence of `str_sword` (Single-quoted WORDs). All the “delimited input”  syntax is defined there: `%Q`, `%q`, `%W`, `%w`, `%x`, `%r`, and `%s` (both versions referenced above define the same set of delimited input markers).

Comment: Chris - Thanks much, that's exactly the information I was looking for.  - Keith

Comment: @True: The links still work for me. Maybe the server was in bad state when you tried them.

Comment: The links are very slow. You can view the source on GitHub much quicker: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L7505-L7554

Answer (score 31):

[Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) mentions them in the [chapter about strings](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_stdtypes.html).

Related to `%q{}` and `%Q{}` is `%{}` which is the same as `%Q{}`. Also, the delimiters "`{}`" I show can be a matching pair of delimiters, so you could use `[]`, `()`, etc. `%q{}` is the same as using single-quotes to delimit a string. `%Q{}` is the same as using double-quotes, allowing embedded strings to be interpolated:

```
%q{foobar} # => "foobar"
%Q{foobar} # => "foobar"

asdf = 'bar' # => "bar"
%q{foo#{asdf}} # => "foo\#{asdf}"
%Q{foo#{asdf}} # => "foobar"
```

Also, there is `%w{}` which splits a string using whitespace, into an array. For instance:

```
%w[a b c] # => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

`%w{}` doesn't interpolate embedded variables:

```
%w[a b asdf] # => ["a", "b", "asdf"]
%w[a b #{asdf}] # => ["a", "b", "\#{asdf}"]
```

And `%r{}` which defines a regular expression:

```
%r{^foo}.class # => Regexp
```

Finally there is `%x{}` which acts like backticks, i.e. "``", passing the string to the underlying operating system. Think of it as "exec":

```
%x{date} # => "Fri Nov 26 15:08:44 MST 2010\n"
```

A lot of Ruby's ideas for these shortcuts come from Perl, only in Perl they use `q{}`, `qq{}`, `qw{}`, `qx{}` and `qr{}`. The leading `q` stands for "quote", and they are treated and documented as "quoting" operators if I remember right. Ruby's documentation needs to be expanded, and this particular set of tools could definitely use some help.

Comment: One correction % is equivalent to %Q and not %q. So you can use %(text#{some_var})

Comment: Correct. Good catch. I probably fat-fingered the shift key. I'll touch it up.

Comment: Ruby docs uses %r in examples without matching delimiters. For example in Class String you can see this: `a.scan(%r\w+/) `. It seems to have a closing '/'. I can't find any where that this usage is documented.

Comment: @WilliamSmith, that's a typographical error in the documentation, it's not an example of acceptable syntax. Try that use of `%r` in IRB and it'll keep gobbling until you type the terminating `\w`. Put that in a script and Ruby will complain about "`unterminated regexp meets end of file`" or something similar. You'll see the same errors in the [Regexp documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html), but try their examples and you'll see that the examples are wrong.

Comment: Ahh. Of course. There are quite a few typos in the online Ruby Docs. But the docs are my bible as I learn the language. Though I now own the latest printed version of "The Ruby Programming Language" by Flanagan and Matz which is a really well written and clean language spec. Highly recommended.

Comment: Another correction: It is not just any matching pair of characters.  %q@this is also a string@ also works.  Almost any character will work and the string will run until that character (unescaped) is repeated.  Alphabetic and numerals don't seem to work though.

Answer (score 5):

They're not keywords, they're macros. It's hard to find an official reference for them, but there's one [here](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#generaldelimitedinput).

Answer (score 1):

> [This note is in response to the discussion between Will and the Tin
>   Man on May 30, 2012  on the topic of regexp literals looking like
>   "%r.../" in the Ruby docs.  I don't seem to be able to add a comment
>   directly to that discussion, but perhaps someone with appropriate
>   privs can move this info over there....]

The general Ruby class documentation is generated from `RDoc` comments built into the source code for  each class in question.  Those source comments have correct syntax for the regular expression literals, as can been see when looking at the text documentation shown via  `ri Regexp`, using locally-generated HTML versions of the documentation, etc.

However, for a period of time this spring, the version of `RDoc` used to generate the documentation pages on [www.ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org) contained a bug that caused the `regexp` literals to show up as `"%r.../"` instead of `"/.../"`.    As of June 9, though, that bug was corrected and the "core" and "std-lib" pages were regenerated, so the regexp literals are displaying correctly again on that site.

(There are other categories of documentation on the site that are generated separately, but if any of those pages still show the incorrect format, they should also get fixed when they eventually get rebuilt.)