# Is there a %w{ }--like way to create array of fixnums in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, notation

Is there a way to create an array of Fixnums using ruby's % notation?

It's obviously quite trivial to write, for example [edit: changed example to nonconsecutive digits]

```
digits = %w{4 8 15 16 23 42}.map{|d| d.to_i}

=> [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
```

but it bugs me and I'm wondering if there is a way to do it without the map.
None of these sources mention such a possibility---am I out of luck?

[What does %w(array) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274675/ruby-what-does-warray-mean)

[What is the %w "thing" in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475830/what-is-the-w-thing-in-ruby)

[Ruby Programming Syntax - the % notation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation)

Comment: Another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287503/where-in-the-ruby-language-is-q-w-etc-defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the % notation seems to be one of those "bastard" Perl string handling inheritances in Ruby I strongly doubt it but you can save a couple of characters by

```
digits = %w{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10}.map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Ooh, I wasn't aware of that syntax possibility. Nice.

Comment: It's called Symbol#to_proc and the wonderful @raganwald / Reginald Braithwaite taught me about it back in 2007. http://weblog.raganwald.com/2007/10/stringtoproc.html It's part of Ruby 1.9 and I think it's been backported to 1.8 as well.

Comment: I can confirm it exists in 1.8.7 even without Rails.

Answer (score 2):

The % notation is specifically about strings, so that won't help you get any closer than the example you gave.

If the integers you care about are consecutive, you could use a Range object:

```
(1..10).to_a
```

Comment: +1, but shouldn't it be `(1..10).to_a`? Without parenthesis, `to_a` is sent to `10:Fixnum`.

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something or does

```
digits = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]

=> [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
```

not do it?

Excellent choice of numbers, btw :)

Comment: :-) and no, you're perfectly correct. That's the 'normal' way to do it. But all those commas! Such a pain!

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.new(10) {|i| i}
```

It's a way of doing it without map.

Comment: Well, yes, in the case of my made-up-for-the-example array that works fine, but I was rather hoping for more of a... general solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could edit parse.y, which turns source code into Ruby, and then re-compile Ruby. I've never edited parse.y myself, but here's an amusing and [awesome talk](http://rubykaigi.org/2011/en/schedule/details/18S01) at RubyKaigi2011 about it.